# The method getLogger(String) is undefined for the type Logger - from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x migration

Tags: log4j2

I am doing migration from Log4j 1.x to Log4j 2.x version

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

The above are the new import statements -

```
Logger.getLogger(ABC.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
Logger.getLogger(XYZ.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

Error which I see is

> The method getLogger(String) is undefined for the type Logger

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The factory method is `LogManager.getLogger` in v2.
See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html

If you don’t want to change any code, there is a bridge available between v1 and v2, see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Comment: Also loggers don't have a `setLevel` method (`LoggerConfig`s do): one of the advantages of logging over `System.out` is that you can change the log level, so the level should not be hardcoded.